# spring boot rabbit consumer vs rest API prioritization

Tags: spring-boot, rabbitmq, spring-rabbit

We are trying to figure out how Srping Boot behvaes in a service which BOTH

a) pulls events from a rabbit queue
b) provides UI with REST API's

The problem is that we would like Spring Boot configured in a way prioritizes REST API's over Rabbit queue. I googled for things like Spring Boot Rest controller buffer etc. but haven't found anything viable.

Spring Boot should have some kind of method that, after processing an event (REST API call or Rabbit pull), checks if there is anything in REST buffer (if such a thing even exists), and only if that is empty, pulls another event from a queue.

We are not even sure if Spring Boot prioritizes Rabbit over REST, but after some UAT it seems it does.

Switching to push pattern with Rabbit seems like an option, but we would like something else.

Also another option was to create replica services: same business logic in two services, one just consuming rabbit, and another offering REST APIs for UI, but this of course adds to DevOps complexity

Answer (score 0):

The two mechanisms are completely independent; the framework provides no  coordination between them.